# Videoconferencing server on linux

Tags: linux, flash, video-conferencing

I need to implement a one-to-one videoconferencing solution server-based, runnable by browser, free (or not expensive), ssl support and good quality video and audio. What would you advise me?

Comment: Are you asking how to develop it or where to find an existing solution ?

Comment: @dystroy Both of them.. Existing solution will be easier, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [WebRTC](http://webrtc.org/).  Chrome and Firefox will be supporting it (early support is in Chrome now, soon will be in Firefox).  It appears Microsoft will be supporting it too - they're hiring engineers specifically for WebRTC work.